# Is there a way to use a for loop to make this more concise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, repeat

```
def rydbergEquation(finalEnergyLevel, initialEnergyLevel):
  return ((1.0974 * 10**7) * (1 / (finalEnergyLevel**2)) - (1 / (initialEnergyLevel**2)))**-1

print("Energy Level (2 to 1):     ", rydbergEquation(1, 2))
print("Energy Level (3 to 1):     ", rydbergEquation(1, 3))
print("Energy Level (4 to 1):     ", rydbergEquation(1, 4))
print("Energy Level (5 to 1):     ", rydbergEquation(1, 5))
print("Energy Level (6 to 1):     ", rydbergEquation(1, 6))
print("Energy Level (7 to 1):     ", rydbergEquation(1, 7))
print("Energy Level (3 to 2):     ", rydbergEquation(2, 3))
print("Energy Level (4 to 2):     ", rydbergEquation(2, 4))
print("Energy Level (5 to 2):     ", rydbergEquation(2, 5))
print("Energy Level (6 to 2):     ", rydbergEquation(2, 6))
print("Energy Level (7 to 2):     ", rydbergEquation(2, 7))
print("Energy Level (4 to 3):     ", rydbergEquation(3, 4))
print("Energy Level (5 to 3):     ", rydbergEquation(3, 5))
print("Energy Level (6 to 3):     ", rydbergEquation(3, 6))
print("Energy Level (7 to 3):     ", rydbergEquation(3, 7))
print("Energy Level (5 to 4):     ", rydbergEquation(4, 5))
print("Energy Level (6 to 4):     ", rydbergEquation(4, 6))
print("Energy Level (7 to 4):     ", rydbergEquation(4, 7))
print("Energy Level (6 to 5):     ", rydbergEquation(5, 6))
print("Energy Level (7 to 5):     ", rydbergEquation(5, 7))
print("Energy Level (7 to 6):     ", rydbergEquation(6, 7))
```

Can I remove the 21 `print` statements and create a for loop to output the given values?

I cannot seem to find a way to loop the function in order to get the outputs of different energy level changes. I assume you can iterate through the range and output the given values, but I am having trouble finding the proper way to do so without having the output look skewed.

By using some sort of double `for` loop, I can see it working.

SOLUTION:
`itertools` has a great combination method that I ended up using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for that purpose:

```
import itertools as it

for i, j in it.combinations(range(1, 8), r=2):
    print(f"Energy Level ({j} to {i}):     ", rydbergEquation(i, j))
```

Comment: @CygnusGames This just replaces the 21 `print` calls.

Answer (score 2):

Itertools is probably better, but for a small case you can probably get by using a double for loop:

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(i+1, 7):
        print(f"Energy Level ({i+1} to {j+1}):     ", rydbergEquation(i+1, j+1))
```

Replace all your print statements with this.

Comment: Thanks, should be fixed for Python versions with f-strings.

Comment: @aganders3 This never runs to `j == 7`, as opposed to the OP.

Comment: @aganders3 Sorry, the other way around, you start `j` at `i+1` and then use `j+1`; this skips the first value of `j`.